# Returning a single Firestore field value from a known documentID

Tags: flutter

I am wanting to do a simple lookup in Firestore to get a 'propertyName' for a given 'propertyID' (the 'properties' documentID) from the collection 'properties' and assign this to the variable propertyName.

The print() gives 'from initstate propertyName = Instance of 'Future' and not the actual value in Firestore. How do I extract the actual value?

I have tried also using StreamBuilder but keep having the same issue.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    var propertyName = _getPropertyNameFromPropertyID(
        widget.propertyID); // to get propertyName from Firestore
    print('from initstate propertyName = $propertyName');
  }

  Future _getPropertyNameFromPropertyID(propertyID) async {
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('properties')
        .document(propertyID)
        .get();
    String result = snapshot['propertyName'].toString();
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your method returns a `Future` so you will need to use `async`/`await` or just get the result directly from the `Future`.

**Option 1**

```
    @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();

        _getPropertyNameFromPropertyID(widget.propertyID).then ((propertyName){
                  print('from initstate propertyName = $propertyName');
            });

      }
```

**Option 2**

```
  @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      _loadAsyncData(); 
    }

    _loadAsyncData() async {
      var propertyName = await _getPropertyNameFromPropertyID(
          widget.propertyID); // to get propertyName from Firestore
      print('from initstate propertyName = $propertyName');
    }

    Future _getPropertyNameFromPropertyID(propertyID) async {
      DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
          .collection('properties')
          .document(propertyID)
          .get();
      String result = snapshot['propertyName'].toString();
      return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks diegoveloper. Both your options certainly work in printing propertyName to the console. But how did I make the variable propertyName available in say a Text widget in body: in Scaffold???

Comment: You can use setState to refresh the widget or use futureBuilder

Comment: Thanks and all working. For beginners like me do note below. The await can not be inside setState. loadPropertyName() async {
    // note that the await cannot be inside setState
    var propertyName = await getPropertyNameFromPropertyID(
        widget.propertyID); // to get propertyName from Firestore
    setState(() {
      displayPropertyName = propertyName;
    });
  }